# Can landscape be used to proxy package updates?

Tags: landscape

I just installed a Landscape server and tried to update one of my clients -- it didn't seem to work.  So, I checked `/var/log/landscape/package-changer.log` on the client, It appears that my client is trying to fetch Ubuntu's repositories.

This is probably not the usual way of using landscape, but is it possible to configure things so my client gets the updates from the landscape server, not the Ubuntu repositories?

My client doesn't have access to the Internet directly.

Answer (score 4):

## Landscape-only Solution

There is a feature in Landscape called 'Repository Management'.  This feature is a bit complex to use and is more intended for people who want to stage updates across all their lab infrastructure.  But, feel free to look it over at the following links:

- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes12.09#Repository_Management
- https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/ch09.html#idp51261860
- https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/repositories.html

Just keep in mind, it lacks a user-friendly view in Landscape.  That major caveat aside, it does work and is seamless from the client point of view -- even supporting private repositories (https).

## Squid Deb Proxy

If you are just wanting to do some proxying of the ubuntu archives though, you should look into squid-deb-proxy:

```
# On the landscape server or any machine your client can see with internet access:
sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy

# On the landscape client (you may have to do this by hand the first time, i.e.,
# download debs and use dpkg -i):
sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy-client
```

If you are using public repositories (like the Ubuntu archive and Launchpad PPAs), this should just work.  But see the docs and the [multitude of questions/answer on squid-deb-proxy here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/squid-deb-proxy) and on the forums if you need help getting things configured.

Comment: Thanks. What I want is being able to do my security updates with Landscape without my Landscape clients having access to the internet. Is Squid Deb Proxy a better solution ?

Comment: @Ignatius: If you have 100 machines and you have a pretty full-blow repository strategy, I would recommend landscape for this task.  If you just have a few clients and only want proxying of ubuntu security updates?  I'd use squid-deb-proxy.